# How to couple Unity Launcher with window opened by IntelliJ?

Tags: unity

I've written a launcher for IntelliJ IDEA. If I start IDEA, the new icon is shown in the Unity Launcher, but with a blank app label. If I Drag and Drop the launcher from Dash to the Unity Launcher, it contains the correct app label with right the X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts. If I start IDEA from the Unity Launcher, new IDEA icon appears.

I'd like to have only one icon in the Unity Launcher, so somehow couple the launcher with the app window.

Answer (score 1):

If you have IDEA 11 then goto `Tools` menu and select `Create Desktop Entry`. Then do any modifications you want to do to the .desktop file which would be created at  ~/.local/share/applications
For more info check out [Custom Launcher for IntelliJ IDEA in Ubuntu Unity](http://nufailm.blogspot.com/2012/05/custom-launcher-for-intellij-idea-in.html)

I don't think this problem can be solved in IDEA versions older than 11. Check out [Java application launcher not staying in Unity launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89442/java-application-launcher-not-staying-in-unity-launcher) and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70806